# Sizing an MFC Window

Tags: c++, mfc

I have an MFC app which I have been working on for a few weeks now, I want to manually set the dimensions of the main frame when it is loaded, can someone give me a hand with this, specifically where to put the code as well?

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can also set the size (with `SetWindowPos()`) from within `CMainFrame::OnCreate()`, or in the `CWinApp`-derived class' `InitInstance`. Look for the line that says `pMainFrame->ShowWindow()`, and call `pMainFrame->SetWindowPos()` before that line. That's where I always do it.

Answer (score 3):

Find your screen size with ..

```
CRect rect;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA,0,&rect,0);
screen_x_size=rect.Width();  
screen_y_size=rect.Height();
```

use these values to calculate the X and Y size of your window then ..

```
::SetWindowPos(m_hWnd,HWND_TOPMOST,0,0,main_x_size,main_y_size,SWP_NOZORDER);
```

Where `main_x_size` and `main_y_size` are your sizes.

Comment: SPI_GETWORKAREA only gets the size of the primary mnonitor. For the entire virtual desktop, use this:
    
    int desktopW = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXVIRTUALSCREEN);
    int desktopH = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYVIRTUALSCREEN);

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for [PreCreateWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4yc5skce(VS.80).aspx) and that your app isn't dialog based.

It's a virtual member function of CWnd class and it's called by framework just before a window is created. So it's a right place to place your changes.

You should write something like this:

```
BOOL CMyWindow::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
   cs.cy = 640; // width
   cs.cx = 480; // height
   cs.y = 0; // top position
   cs.x = 0; // left position
   // don't forget to call base class version, suppose you derived you window from CWnd
   return CWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs);
}
```

Comment: It works, but you have to edit `PreCreateWindow` in `MainFrm.cpp`, not your View class.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this:

```
CRect rect;
SystemParametersInfo(SPI_GETWORKAREA, 0, &rect, 0);
left = -3, right = 3;
rect.top = 100;
rect.bottom = 500;
rect.left = 100;
rect.right = 800;
//or use
CRect cr;
cr.SetRect(POINT{ 100,100 }, POINT{ 500,800 });
MoveWindow(rect);
```

Comment: You haven't answered the full question nor have you explained how your code works. Please help the asker out by providing a little context around your answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
BOOL YourProjectApp::InitInstance()
{
        :
        :
    m_pMainWnd->MoveWindow(0, 0, 1900, 1000);  // add this line for fixing the default size of mainWindow
    m_pMainWnd->ShowWindow(SW_SHOW);
    m_pMainWnd->UpdateWindow();
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Please read [answer].

Comment: See "[Explaining entirely code-based answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/128421)". While this might be technically correct, it doesn't explain why it solves the problem or should be the selected answer. We should educate along with helping solve the problem.