# Set the size of a window in MFC application

Tags: c++, mfc, window

This question may be considered as naive for many users but I am new to MFC and I need an indication. I want to set a specific size to a SDI window but I fail to do it. I try the code in the CMainFrame class:

```
BOOL CMainFrame::PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs)
{
if( !CFrameWndEx::PreCreateWindow(cs) )
    return FALSE;

 cs.style = WS_OVERLAPPED | WS_SYSMENU | WS_BORDER;

 cs.cy = 600; 
 cs.cx = 600; 
 cs.y = ((cs.cy * 3) - cs.cy) / 2; 
 cs.x = ((cs.cx * 3) - cs.cx) / 2;


 return CFrameWnd::PreCreateWindow(cs); 
}
```

The window still keeps its size though without any change.

As far as I am concerned, I can override the respective function in CWnd class to get to the same result. Given that I have not used the CWnd class till now in my program, how can I do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Sizing an MFC Window](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/178326/sizing-an-mfc-window)

Answer (score 0):

Move your code above the call of `CFrameWndEx::PreCreateWindow`

Comment: When I delete  the lines if( !CFrameWndEx::PreCreateWindow(cs) )
    return FALSE;. the program crashes. If I put the additional code above of it, nothing is changed again. The problem is that the function in any case returns FALSE. How I get over this?

Comment: Just to check: run your application (with changes above), move and resize main application's window, and close application. Then start the application again. Is app's window on previous place or not?

Answer (score 0):

Is  your class really derived from CFrameWndEx? And is that the class you have in the IMPLEMENT_DYNANIC / IMPLEMENT_DYNCREATE line? And in the BEGIN_MESSSAGE_MAP line?

Think also on adding a `ON_WM_CREATE` to your message map and its `OnCreate`method for allowing other possibilities:

- Do a similar thing to what you are doing int this new method.
- Use `SetWindowPos` here